# Crossbrowser compatibility with React/Angular

Tags: angular, reactjs, css, cross-browser

As I am novice in web development I want to ask for clarification in following issues:

1) What is the best practice to avoid crossbrowser issues (I found a lot of varianced info about that). I need clear, simple 'recipe' - what I should do first, next and so on.

2) Related to point 1 what should we do when we want to keep crossbrowser compatibility AND get rid off JQuery from our project ?

3) If we have React/Angular with preprocessors (SASS) and framework such as Flexbox/Bootstrap on our disposal what else can or should we do to create professional-looking website in terms of crossbrowser compatibility?

Comment: 'Crossbrowser issues' don't have a specific meaning. Can the fact that modern website doesn't work in IE8 be considered a crossbrowser issue? *What is the best practice to avoid crossbrowser issues (I found a lot of varianced info about that). I need clear, simple 'recipe'* - check every single feature you're using in MDN documentation and https://caniuse.com/ and also check whether it can be polyfilled and to which degree. Can this be considered simple enough? There are no shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

I can speak from an Angular standpoint

1.) I wouldn't say there is a distinct recipe as much as there are some guidelines to remember as you develop. One of the biggest things to look out for is anything in your code that directly references the DOM. It is generally discouraged to directly reference the DOM as different browsers return different objects when you reference elements in the DOM. If you're using Angular, make sure to use `"@angular/platform-browser": "<ANGULAR_VERSION>", "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "<ANGULAR_VERSION>"`, and as always, make sure the versions of those dependencies match the versions of the rest of your `@angular` dependencies. It's also worth looking into [Angular Polyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-polyfills), as they can help you support some browsers that are trickier than other. Always remember to test your code on different browsers frequently.

2.) This really depends on how you're using jquery. There are many ways to replace jquery with parts of Angular like `*ngFor` or `*ngIf`. The templating of Angular components is pretty flexible, and you can have the page dynamically update itself by using angular functions and using [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----) that references variables that you can dynamically with the functions in your components.

3.) If you're using NPM, I would look into using the [scss-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-bundle) dependency. If you're also using webpack, you should also be able to easily import styles from frameworks like bootstrap, i.e. `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`. All you need to do is make sure you have the bootstrap dependency installed in NPM. In general, Frameworks already consider cross browser support (among other things like accessibility and responsiveness) when they generate their style.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what browsers you are targeting. There is no magic bullet for Cross Browser compatibility. You can use browserstack to see how your site looks in many different browsers. You can also use Chrome dev tools and choose emulation to see what it looks like on certain phones. Keep in mind, React typically is written in ES6 syntax and uses Babel to transpile it to ES5 code, which allows modern browsers to interpret. SASS converts code to plain css, so your browser compatibility depends on the properties used. For that you can use [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/)